# How to reload page once state or data is changed within a react class using component did mount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express

Within my react app, I am calling my router which retrives all of the animals in my mongo db, I then filter this based upon the favourite status of the animal. I am loading this data into a list called animals that I store within the state of the class. I have some buttons on each individual card for each animal which change the state of the animal's status (modded by is set in the react app and the status is set to favourite within my express route) and potentially will remove them from the list of animals displayed. However, this list of animals does not automatically update when this state is changed like how I expected it to (once an animal is changed to favourite then I don't want to see it on the Non-favourite list). I am not sure how to achieve this - I am wanting the animal list to be reloaded with the new information when a change is made to an animal card.

Code for the component I am having issues with:

```js
export default class AnimalListing extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      animals: null,
      update: '',
    };
  }

  starAnimal = async (values) => {
    var moddedby = sessionStorage.getItem('username');
    const data = {
      modified_by: moddedby,
    };

    fetch(`http://localhost:4000/assign/animal/starred/${values}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    }).then((res) => {
      console.log('success');
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/animals`, {}).then((animal) => {
      this.setState({ animals: animal.data });
    });
  }

  render() {
    var Nonfavourite;
    Nonfavourite = this.state.tickets
      .filter((ticket) => animal.status === 'Non-favourite')
      .map((ticket) => (
        <div class="card-columns">
          <div class="card bg-light">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
              <h4 class="animal">{animal.name}</h4>
              <p>{animal.information}</p>
              <p>{animal.status}</p>

              <Button
                variant="primary"
                type="button"
                onClick={() => this.starAnimal(animal._id)}
              >
                Favourite this animal
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ));

    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Animals</h4>
        {Nonfavourite}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Route in express**

```js
export const starAnimal = (req, res) => {
  var filter = { _id: req.params._id };
  var update = {
    $set: {
      status: 'Favourite',
      modified_by: req.body.modified_by,
    },
  };

  Animal.updateOne(filter, update, (err, a) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    } else {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: 'animal is now a favourite',
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Basically you need the api call in componentdidmount to be called on success of starAnimal() method right?

Comment: I need the API call to be done first I thought as that's what I use to populate the cards and on the cards the user can star the selected animal card. Like if I don't call the API get then there are no animals avaliable to star @AkhilChandran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the api call in componentDidMount a seperate function like,

```
const getAnimals = () => {
  axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/animals`, {
        
    })
    .then((animal)=> {
        this.setState({animals: animal.data})   
    }
}
```

Then call this function in starAnimal

```
starAnimal = async values => {

    var moddedby = sessionStorage.getItem("username");
     

    const data = {
        modified_by:  moddedby
    }

    fetch(`http://localhost:4000/assign/animal/starred/${values}`, {
    method:'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify(data)})        
}).then(res =>{
    console.log("success");
   // refetching the animals
    this.getAnimals();
})
```

Also call it inside componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.getAnimals();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm just confused as to where I would define the getAnimals function as if I declare it outside of the class then when I call it I get the error: "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): undefined has no properties" against the line "this.setState({animals:animal.data})"

Comment: Define it inside the class like you did with starAnimal. Then call it inside success of starAnimal and componentDidMount

Comment: This does not work for me sadly as it gives me errors saying that getAnimals() is undefined when I call it in componentDidMount and in starAnimals. @Akhil Chandran

Comment: Fixed it by calling it using this.getAnimals() rather than getAnimals()

Comment: Oops, been using functional components for a long now :). I barely remember "this" keyword existed.